# How to select and change URL into a text using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I have a text like this:

```
Tapez ici le message que vous souhaitez envoyer à vos clients http://go.tanger.fr/m/125
```

I have already created a regex to select the link:

```
/(http(s)?:\/\/go.tanger.fr\/m\/)(\d+)/i
```

I want to change the link so that it looks like this:

```
http://go.tanger.fr/m/125?id=xxx
```

Comment: this a id from my server that what i should add to my link

Comment: Didn't you mix up the input and output? Your regex is for matching some different link types.

Comment: So you have `http://go.tanger.fr/m/125` and want to go to `http://go.tanger.fr/m/125?id=xxx`? Do you want to do this in the source of your page or as rewrite/redirect (pretty URLs)?

Comment: No i just want to change it in my text that all http://go.tanger.fr/m/125 => http://go.tanger.fr/m/125?id=xxx

Comment: How do you get the ID? Something like this I'd start with `~https?://go\.tanger\.fr/m/(\d+)~i`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want to use the last digits as a query string.

You can achieve this with

```
$re = "#(https?):\/\/go\.tanger\.fr\/m\/(\d+)#i"; 
$str = "Tapez ici le message que vous souhaitez envoyer à vos clients https://go.tanger.fr/m/123"; 
$subst = "$1://go.tanger.fr/m/125?id=$2"; 
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Here is [an IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/8DHMis)

Comment: Does it work for you or do you need more assistance with this?

Answer (score 0):

Use ($string is the string in which you want to change):

```
preg_replace('/(http(s)?:\/\/dominos.mylittlebiz.fr\/m\/)(\d+)/i', 'http://go.tanger.fr/m/\1?ID=XXX', $string);
```